# How to DEcentralize a div in a div - horizontally?

Tags: html, css, margin

It's continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally).
Can we decentralize div box from the center? But keep zoom on the box.

Two requirements:

1. Small resolutions (f.i. iPad) it keeps centralized;
2. Large resolution it takes (f.i. 20% from the left side).

Unfortunately `left: -300px;` doesn't work.
Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ESVFL/).

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#bg-rect-important {
    background-color: #656565;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    min-width: 980px;   /* max for iPad */  
    height: 263px;
}

#base-rect-lime {
    background-color: lime;
    height:400px;
    width:940px;
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bg-rect" id="bg-rect-important">
    <div id="base-rect-lime"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using media queries to target the smaller devices?

Comment: Probably my question "what is it?" will be an answer for you. :)

Comment: Thank you. It might be an answer for cell phone and iPad, but still... I wish decentralize the box on 20%-30% of an empty space on displays.

Comment: Are there other ways of resolving the question? It will require me to write 4 css files. Rectangle, square, iPad, cell phone.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  I don't see how this requires more than 1 CSS file:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/JCjav